# Meteor: User account management and creation by Admin only

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am new to Meteor and have been playing with some common packages such as:

1. accounts-password
2. accounts-ui

accounts-ui

and a few others that allow role creation and assignment using admin users such as :

1. mrt:accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3

These packages seem to allow the public to create user accounts on the public site, and the admin has to login and create/assign roles to these user accounts. The admin however, is not allowed to create user accounts from the admin page.

The features which I cannot find, which I now intend to build myself are:

1. User **account creation** AND **role assignment** is managed via admins only in an admin page.
2. User account creation is not allowed on the public website (you can only login)

I thus have to properly understand how the accounts system works. Does anyone have any pointers on where i can start reading, or have any advice, or is aware of any existing packages that might suit my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a system like this forking The Meteor Chef's 'base' project.

https://github.com/themeteorchef/base

Here's a complete walkthrough of how to build what you're asking for:

https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/building-a-user-admin/

Underneath the covers, the alanning:roles package is a staple of any system like this.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, this link looks pretty awesome. I am going to dive into it